# How to upload three different files from the same page using Django?

Tags: django

I want to upload multiple files form the same html page in Django , and the models should dynamically change according to the file uploaded . How do I do that ?

Comment: "the models should dynamically change" Are you STILL at this?

Comment: Yes . Weirdly , I am still at that . Though , I do have a sense of what needs to be done , it kind of perplexes me as ogrinspect would generate a dynamic model for me . But how do I put it in Models.py after doing certain additional changes to it .

Comment: You can have all the sense of what needs to be done in the world, but if Django doesn't do it then Django doesn't do it.

Comment: Can you update your question to give an example of how the "models should dynamically change"?

Comment: It wouldn't be called a [model](http://www.google.hr/search?ie=UTF-8&q=define%3Amodel) if it would change all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery form plugin - http://jquery.malsup.com/form/